# What does the utcoffset method do in datetime - Python

Tags: python, datetime

I know this questions answer is usually "go to [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=utcoffset#datetime.datetime.utcoffset)". I have read it and am still not a 100% sure what the uctcoffset method does.

I assume that it takes the timezone - utc and gives the difference but I need to be 100% sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, it is doing exactly what you think it does. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=utcoffset#datetime.tzinfo.utcoffset) are the official docs.

Edit:
To be precise, it does not take a timezone, it takes 0 paramters. You  invoke it on a datimeobject, that object has a timezone associated to it, if it is timezone aware. In that case the method wil return a timedelta object, which represents the differenc between the timezone of the datetime object and utc

Comment: Maybe also add the link to https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=utcoffset#datetime.tzinfo.utcoffset. This makes it very clear, at least to me.

Comment: agreed, was just skipping that since the thread opener allready provided that link

Answer (score 6):

The `utcoffset` method of a `datetime` gives you the difference between the "wall clock" time of the datetime and the "wall clock" time of the same point in time in UTC, so, exactly as you expect (`dt - dt_as_utc`). The reason it is a function is that for many time zones (such as those with daylight savings), the offset changes over the course of a year. As an example:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil import tz

NYC = tz.gettz('America/New_York')  # Note: ambiguous time support
                                    # requires version >= 2.6.0, be aware.

dt1 = datetime(2015, 5, 21, 12, 0, tzinfo=NYC)    # EST
dt2 = datetime(2015, 12, 21, 12, 0, tzinfo=NYC)   # EDT

print(dt1.utcoffset() / timedelta(hours=1))
# -4
print(dt1.tzname())
# EDT


print(dt2.utcoffset() / timedelta(hours=1))
# -5
print(dt2.tzname())
# EST
```

As you can see, the same applies to the `tzname()` function.  For naive datetimes (those with no datetime), `utcoffset()` and `tzname()` should both return `None`.

As a note, I would generally advise *not* using this function to *calculate* a UTC timestamp, rather, you should use `astimezone()` with either [`dateutil.tz.tzutc`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tz.html#dateutil.tz.tzutc) or `pytz.UTC` or, if you are using Python version >= 3.2, you can use the [`datetime.timezone.utc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timezone) object.