# Calculate difference between CET and UTC to handle daylight saving automatically

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, difference, dst

I am trying to handle daylight saving time (DST) in my code in more automatic way.
I want to calculate if difference between current UTC and CET time is one hour or two hours.
I have two variables which shows current datetime in UTC and CET. Since, time is same, I am getting their difference as 0 and not as 2. Below is my code. Any suggestions will be helpful.

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
import pytz

date = pd.to_datetime(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
cet_now = datetime.now(pytz.timezone("CET"))
utc_now = datetime.now(pytz.timezone("UTC"))
h = abs((cet_now-utc_now)).total_seconds()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the utcoffset method do in datetime - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40695295/what-does-the-utcoffset-method-do-in-datetime-python)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution of my question.
'''

```
cet_now = datetime.now(pytz.timezone("CET")).hour
utc_now = datetime.now(pytz.timezone("UTC")).hour
h = abs(cet_now - utc_now)
```

'''
Above worked.

Comment: although that *works*, 3 suggestions for improvement: use [utcoffset](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcoffset) method - much simpler, directly gives you the timedelta. Use [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) - pytz is deprecated. And instead of tz abbreviations, it is better to use a [IANA time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), here e.g. "Europe/Berlin". Many abbreviations are ambiguous.