# How do you get the UTC time offset in Python now that utcnow() is deprecated?

Tags: python, datetime, unix-timestamp

I need the time difference in sec between my current location and UTC. It worked so well with (example timezone Berlin, UTC+1h) :

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp(): 1699017779.016835
datetime.datetime.now().timestamp():    1699021379.017343 # 3600 sec larger, correct!
```

But now `utcnow()` is marked as deprecated, and I need `now()` and load it with a timezone object:

```
datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc): 2023-11-03 14:22:59.018573+00:00
datetime.datetime.now():                      2023-11-03 15:22:59.018941    # 1 h later, correct!
```

Also giving correct result. But as I want the timestamp, I do as before, but get the wrong result:

```
datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).timestamp()) 1699021379.019286 # UTC  : is actually local timestamp
datetime.datetime.now().timestamp())                      1699021379.019619 # Local: why no difference ???
```

Local is correct, but UTC is now giving the exact same timestamp as Local, and this wrong! Am I missing anything or is this simply a bug?

**EDIT:**

After reviewing all the comments I disagree with some commenters - I see nothing wrong with utcnow(). It does give the UTC timestamp for the moment of calling. Of course there is no timezone involved when you ask for UTC time! What does seem wrong is to use timestamps for other places which include the time difference to UTC and view this as a UTC/UNIX timestamp?

But perhaps I should make my needs clearer: I want the time difference between my timezone and UTC in seconds. Is there a simpler way to get this in Python?

None of the answers and comments provide an answer to this question.

**EDIT2**

I found 2 possible workarounds:

```
import datetime as dt
# workaround #1
ts = time.time()
utc   = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts, tz=datetime.timezone.utc)                     # 2023-11-06 11:49:30.154083+00:00
local = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts, tz=None)                                      # 2023-11-06 12:49:30.154083
ts_utc   = dt.datetime.strptime(str(utc)  [0:19], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timestamp()  # 1699267770.0
ts_local = dt.datetime.strptime(str(local)[0:19], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timestamp()  # 1699271370.0  # more by 3600 sec
TimeZoneOffset = ts_local - ts_utc                                                  # +3600 (sec)

# workaround #2
TimeZoneOffset = dt.datetime.now().astimezone().utcoffset().total_seconds()         # +3600 (sec)
```

Comment: Does this work? `datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(now.timestamp()).timestamp()`?

Comment: `datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp(): 1699017779.016835` - this is why the method was deprecated in the first place. It is misleading and error-prone since the result is NOT Unix time for the datetime returned from utcnow().

Comment: as for what you consider "wrong", Unix time refers to UTC, so both timestamps ***must*** in fact be identical.

Comment: Though I was under the impression the unix timestamps were constant with respect to timezone. So, if that works it is kind of funky

Comment: Timestamps are not local.  They are global.  That is part of their usefulness.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do UNIX timestamps change across timezones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062515/do-unix-timestamps-change-across-timezones) Also: [Why does datetime.datetime.utcnow() not contain timezone information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331592/why-does-datetime-datetime-utcnow-not-contain-timezone-information)

Comment: Also for the specific purpose you have: [What does the utcoffset method do in datetime - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40695295/what-does-the-utcoffset-method-do-in-datetime-python)

Comment: @JonSG: Thx, this does indeed serve as a workaround. 
Though I can't find anything wrong with utcnow(). It does give the proper UTC timestamp in the moment of calling.
All I need is the the time difference between my location and UTC in seconds. Is there no simpler way?

Comment: @JonSG: Bummer, from Py3.12 on I get the same deprecation warning for 'utcfromtimestamp()' as for 'utcnow()'  :-(
 
DeprecationWarning: datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp() is deprecated and scheduled for removal in a future version. Use timezone-aware objects to represent datetimes in UTC: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, datetime.UTC).

Comment: @ullix Would `datetime.datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=None) - datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).replace(tzinfo=None)` work for you?

Comment: @Florian: No, but I found 2 possible workarounds (which I just added as EDIT2 to my original post, see above) which do give me the time difference to UTC in seconds.

Answer (score 4):

The unix time stamp is the number of seconds since 00:00:00 on January 1, 1970 UTC.  It is a global value not local, which is what makes it useful.

The issues is actually with `utcnow`.  Either you have your original example code answers inverted or you are located east of Greenwich where your timezone is ahead of the UTC and you should have actually been expecting a smaller timestamp from `utcnow`.  For me, where I am 4 hours behind UTC time (i.e. west of Greewich).

```
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp()
1699038850.622385
>>> datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
1699024453.862131
>>>
```

So, for me it is the utcnow timestamp that is larger.  The problem is that `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` generates a `datetime.datetime` object that doesn't have timezone information embedded.  So, when you call timestamp on it you get the timestamp for when your local time is what the UTC time is now.

I expect this is part of why `utcnow` is deprecated.

Comment: As I had stated I am in timezone Berlin, UTC+1h, i.e. east of Greenwich, and my now() and utcnow() results show that. utcnow() may not have a timezone embedded, but by definition is doesn't need one, as it is independent of timezone.
For me utcnow() is correct. Problematic looks to me that the other timestamps incorporate the timezone differences, while being designated as UNIX time. Which they are not when we assume that UNIX time == UTC time.
utcnow() is correct and should NOT be deprecated!

Comment: @ullix in support of Malcolm's answer - "*utcnow() may not have a timezone embedded, but by definition is doesn't need one*" -> this is not how datetime as a data structure works conceptually. The point is that naive datetime (no tzinfo attached) is *interpreted* as local time in Python, no matter if it's coming from datetime.now or datetime.utcnow. But, "utcnow" suggests that it's interpreted as UTC, which it is not. Imho, the actual problem is in Python datetime's design to say naive == local. In combination with Unix time methods, that's a shot to the foot.